# Curl not responding in php

Tags: php, curl

I am working of current currency rate so i did use yahoo finance link, but in curl i didn't get any reply 
i have tried to set content type but it doesn't work Please help me

```
$url=urlencode("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ('USDUSD','USDEUR','USDGBP','USDINR','USDAED','INRINR','INREUR','INRGBP','INRAED','INRUSD')&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys");

        $request = curl_init(); 
        $timeOut = 0; 
        curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)"); 
        curl_setopt ($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut); 
        curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:  application/xml'));

        $response = curl_exec($request); 

        print_r(curl_getinfo($request));
        curl_close($request);
```

getting response as

```
Array
(
    [url] => HTTP://http%3A%2F%2Fquery.yahooapis.com%2Fv1%2Fpublic%2Fyql%3Fq%3Dselect+%2A+from+yahoo.finance.xchange+where+pair+in+%28%27USDUSD%27%2C%27USDEUR%27%2C%27USDGBP%27%2C%27USDINR%27%2C%27USDAED%27%2C%27INRINR%27%2C%27INREUR%27%2C%27INRGBP%27%2C%27INRAED%27%2C%27INRUSD%27%29%26env%3Dstore%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys/
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
```

Comment: You should also check http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are urlencoding the url, which mutilates it. Try

```
$url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
$url .= urlencode("select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ('USDUSD','USDEUR','USDGBP','USDINR','USDAED','INRINR','INREUR','INRGBP','INRAED','INRUSD')");
$url .= "&env=";
$url .= urlencode("store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"));
```

**EDIT**

Didn't see the second GET parameter at first, updated code.

Comment: thank you Eugen  but i made some changes in your answer like this

$url="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" . urlencode("select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ('USDUSD','USDEUR','USDGBP','USDINR','USDAED','INRINR','INREUR','INRGBP','INRAED','INRUSD')")."&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"; 


 this works for me :D